# How to get Mellin transform of the given function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, mellin-transform

Could anyone help me how to find Mellin transform of the following function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^a-A)^3},$$ i.e. the integral $$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}\,{\rm d}x}{(x^a-A)^3}$$ where $a,A>0\,.$

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: I have tried to find similar integrals in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, but no success. On the other hand, I tried with some substitutions, but also no success.

Answer (score 1):

- If $A > 0$ then it is a principal value, thus the mean value of $A+i\epsilon,A-i\epsilon$. Whence we can assume $A\not \in [0,\infty)$
- With a change of variable we get $a=1$. With another one we get $\mathcal{M}[\frac1{(x+1)^3}]$
- The residue theorem gives for $c\in (0,1),x\ne 1$ $$\frac1{x+1}=\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)} x^{-s}ds$$
  Differentiating we get 
  $$\frac2{(x+1)^3}=\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}s(s+1)  x^{-s-2}ds$$

$$\implies \mathcal{M}[\frac2{(x+1)^3}]=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi (s-2))}(s-2)(s-1)\qquad (\Re(s)\in (0,3))$$

Comment: I  have tried to get your result, but there are some problems. What change of variable you have used and get $a=1$? What about $A$? It should be $A>0$.

Comment: $pv(\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{(x^a-A)^3}dx)=\frac12\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{(x^a-A+i\epsilon)^3}dx+\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{(x^a-A-i\epsilon)^3}dx$ then do the change of variable $y = -x^a/ (A+i\epsilon)$, being careful with the implied branch of $(-A-i\epsilon)^{s-1}$